# How to cancel shutdown on Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, exit, shutdown, process-control

I'm familiar with and use `shutdown` in Linux, and typically just do

`> shutdown -h now`

But is there a way to stop shutdown from happening, say if I aim to shutdown 10 minutes from now and then in 5 minutes' time I discover I really don't want to shut down?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use  `ps`  to find the shutdown process and abort it, for example with `ps|grep shutdown`.

Alternate and less eyeball-intensive versions of this:

```
pkill shutdown
killall shutdown
kill `cat /var/run/shutdown.pid`
```

Comment: so `pkill shutdown` would work?

Comment: Yeah.  Seems suboptimal if (and only if) your shutdown supports -c, though.

Comment: Alternatively: "killall shutdown"

Comment: Hmm... I thought shutdown only ran long enough to change the run level... He's probably asking how to get init to STOP shutting down.

Comment: @dicroce: If you start a shutdown scheduled for some future time, like he talks about in the question, shutdown runs (hangs out, really) until it's time to actually shut down.  The question is how to stop it during that time.

Comment: On OS X this cancels shutdown but then you need to delete /etc/nologin because it causes that only root can log in.

Answer (score 104):

`shutdown -c`  is "cancel shutdown" on reasonably recent `shutdown`s.

The syntax also supports `shutdown -c <message>` for announcement purposes, so that's handy if other people use the machine.

Comment: Which distro is that for? http://man.cx/shutdown doesn't mention a -c flag.

Comment: But this does: http://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown

Comment: Exists on vaguely recent Debian, dunno what else.

Comment: Works on current versions of Redhat distros.

Comment: I was just looking this up in Ubuntu last night; it's in the man page for their version... well, the system shutdown just as I read that, though!

Answer (score 11):

If you're a second late on the draw for `shutdown -c`, and already root on the console, a very fast `# init 5` will cancel a shutdown after init changes runlevel.

NOTE: This answer is mostly obsolete now. `init 5` isn't very useful on systemd, which, sadly, most systems now use.

Answer (score 8):

From `shutdown`'s man page on BSD systems:

> A scheduled shutdown can be canceled
>   by killing the shutdown process (a
>   SIGTERM should suffice).